# Reference an ALIAS in a SUM funciton - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, alias

### Background:

I am trying to calculate the profit margin inside of the query and I am running into errors. When I try to use the select statement in the SUM function, I trigger an error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

I understand that this is caused by having a SELECT query inside of the SUM function. From there, I tried to reference the alias of the COGS column. I recieve an error when I do that as well:

> Invalid column name 'COGS'.

After messing around with the query some more, I figured it might be due to fact that I'm trying all of this inside of a SUM function and so I removed that and ran the query. It returned a few errors:

> - Column 'tbl_invoice.subTotal' is invalid in the select list because    it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> - Column 'tbl_invoice.tradeinAmount' is invalid in the select list because it    is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>     GROUP BY    clause.
> - Column    'tbl_invoice.subTotal' is invalid in the select list because it is    not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>     GROUP BY clause.
> - Column    'tbl_invoice.tradeinAmount' is invalid in the select list because it    is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>     GROUP BY    clause.
> - Column    'tbl_invoice.subTotal' is invalid in the select list because it is    not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>     GROUP BY clause.
> - Column    'tbl_invoice.tradeinAmount' is invalid in the select list because it    is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>     GROUP BY    clause.

Is there another way to use or reference the value I need in the SUM function?

---

### Query:

```
--Main query
SELECT 
custID,
COUNT(custID) AS InvoiceNum,

--This is the column that has an alias
(SELECT cogs FROM #tempMarketing where #tempMarketing.custID = tbl_invoice.custID) as COGS,
--This is where I am trying to calculate the profit margin
SUM(((((subTotal + (-1 * tradeinAmount) - (SELECT cogs FROM #tempMarketing where #tempMarketing.custID = tbl_invoice.custID))) 
/ (NULLIF(subTotal + (-1 * tradeinAmount),0))) *100)) as Profitmargin, 

FROM tbl_invoice 
group by custID
order by InvoiceNum desc;
```

Comment: Just join to #tempMarketing and use conditional aggregation and avoid the subquery all together - see example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
a.custID,
COUNT(a.custID) AS InvoiceNum,  case when a.custid=b.custid then b.cogs else 0 end 
 as COGS,
SUM(((((subTotal + (-1 * tradeinAmount) - case when a.custid=b.custid then b.cogs else 0 end)) 
/ (NULLIF(subTotal + (-1 * tradeinAmount),0))) *100)) as Profitmargin, 

FROM tbl_invoice a 
left join #tempMarketing b on a.custID =b.custid
group by a.custID, 
case when a.custid=b.custid then b.cogs else null end 
order by InvoiceNum desc;
```

Comment: I've never seen `case when a.custid=b.custid then cogs else 0 ` written like this. Why not use `ISNULL()`? Also, while this may work, I'd explicitly alias all the columns in the select lists as we can't be certain what columns are in both tables, which would cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query, I have created a common table expression for cogs column:

```
WITH cte_base AS(
SELECT cogs FROM #tempMarketing where #tempMarketing.custID = tbl_invoice.custID
)
SELECT 
custID,
COUNT(custID) AS InvoiceNum,

--This is the column that has an alias
cte_base.cogs as COGS,
--This is where I am trying to calculate the profit margin
SUM(((((subTotal + (-1 * tradeinAmount) - (cte_base.cogs))) 
/ (NULLIF(subTotal + (-1 * tradeinAmount),0))) *100)) as Profitmargin, 

FROM tbl_invoice 
group by custID
order by InvoiceNum desc;
```